# Problem with case statement and dynamic table name

Tags: postgresql, case, debugging

I have the following case statement

```sql
case %1$s::text
  when ''lookup_relation_job'' then
    case %1$s.relation
      when ''followers'' then ''get-followers''
      when ''following'' then ''get-following''
      when ''blocking'' then ''get-blocking''
      when ''muting'' then ''get-muting''
    end
  when ''manage_list_members_job'' then
    case %1$s.add
      when true then ''add-list-member''
      else ''remove-list-member''
    end
  when ''manage_relation_job'' then
    case %1$s.relation
      when ''follow'' then
        case %1$s.add
          when true then ''add-follow''
          else ''remove-follow''
        end
      when ''block'' then
        case %1$s.add
          when true then ''add-block''
          else ''remove-block''
        end
      when ''mute'' then
        case %1$s.add
          when true then ''add-mute''
          else ''remove-mute''
        end
    end
end
```

Here `%1$s` is an argument of type `regclass`.

When I run the above with `%1$s` = `lookup_relation_job`, Postgres throws an error saying: `column lookup_relation_job.add does not exist`. But it shouldn't even check for the add column when the argument is `lookup_relation_job` according to the case logic. What's going wrong here?

I suspect either there's some kind of fall-through happening here (I double checked that I've closed all `case` statements with `end`), or Postgres checks for all the conditions even if the parent condition is false (this is unlikely).

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: Below is the whole relevant PL/pgSQL function

```sql
create or replace function get_jobs_to_add
  (job_table regclass, active_jobs bigint[], failed_jobs bigint[], out result bigint[])
  as $$
begin
execute format('
  select array(
    select
    distinct on (%1$s.user_id)
    %1$s.id
  from %1$s
    left join user_profile on user_profile.id = %1$s.user_id
    left join twitter_api_rate_limit on
      twitter_api_rate_limit.user_twitter_id = user_profile.twitter_id and
      twitter_api_rate_limit.endpoint = (
        case %1$s::text
          when ''lookup_relation_job'' then
            case %1$s.relation
              when ''followers'' then ''get-followers''
              when ''following'' then ''get-following''
              when ''blocking'' then ''get-blocking''
              when ''muting'' then ''get-muting''
            end
          when ''manage_list_members_job'' then
            case %1$s.add
              when true then ''add-list-member''
              else ''remove-list-member''
            end
          when ''manage_relation_job'' then
            case %1$s.relation
              when ''follow'' then
                case %1$s.add
                  when true then ''add-follow''
                  else ''remove-follow''
                end
              when ''block'' then
                case %1$s.add
                  when true then ''add-block''
                  else ''remove-block''
                end
              when ''mute'' then
                case %1$s.add
                  when true then ''add-mute''
                  else ''remove-mute''
                end
            end
        end
      )
  where %1$s.finished = false
    and %1$s.paused = false
    and %1$s.deleted = false
    and (twitter_api_rate_limit.resets_at is null or twitter_api_rate_limit.resets_at < now())
    and not (%1$s.id = any(%3$L))
    and %1$s.user_id not in (
      select user_id from %1$s where id = any(%2$L)
    )
  order by %1$s.user_id, %1$s.priority desc
);', job_table, active_jobs, failed_jobs) into result;

end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Is that really a PL/pgSQL [CASE _statement_](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#id-1.8.8.8.6.6) or a [CASE **expression**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) that is part of a SQL query?

Comment: It's inside an `EXECUTE format()` statement of PL/pgSQL function @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the whole code in the context of the function. As written, it doesn't make sense as a statement (because no PL/PgSQL code is executed), only as an expression that could be used to store the result into a variable.

Comment: Makes sense, added the whole function as an edit to the OP.

Comment: Well, that's a CASE _expression_ (in SQL)

Answer (score 1):

After the parameter has been substituted, the SQL statement will look like

```
...
case 'mytable'::text
  when 'lookup_relation_job' then
    case mytable.relation
...
```

When this statement is parsed (before it is executed), `mytable.relation` gets resolved and throws an error.  Consider [this note](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) in the documentation:

> As described in [Section 4.2.14](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-EXPRESS-EVAL), there are various situations in which subexpressions of an expression are evaluated at different times, so that the principle that “`CASE` evaluates only necessary subexpressions” is not ironclad. For example a constant `1/0` subexpression will usually result in a division-by-zero failure at planning time, even if it's within a `CASE` arm that would never be entered at run time.

You will probably have to split this up into several queries.